# how to return the value of an input parameter in a for loop

Tags: python, function, loops, return

I have the following function in python

```
def find_new_similar(tfidf_matrix2, index, tfidf_matrix, top_n = 1):
    cosine_similarities = linear_kernel(tfidf_matrix2[index:index+1], tfidf_matrix).flatten()
    related_docs_indices = [i for i in cosine_similarities.argsort()[::-1] if i != index]
    return [(index, cosine_similarities[index]) for index in related_docs_indices][0:top_n]
```

where upon calling this I get something like:

```
>>> find_new_similar(tfidf_matrix2, 40, tfidf_matrix)

([(260816, 0.55759049663331683)])
```

which is the index of `related_docs_indices` and the result of `cosine_similarities` for the index *given as an input to my function*. I would also like to return the intial index `i` that I pass to the function. I have tried :

```
def find_new_similar(tfidf_matrix2, index, tfidf_matrix, top_n = 1):
    cosine_similarities = linear_kernel(tfidf_matrix2[index:index+1], tfidf_matrix).flatten()
    related_docs_indices = [i for i in cosine_similarities.argsort()[::-1] if i != index]
    return [(index, cosine_similarities[index]) for index in related_docs_indices][0:top_n], index
```

i.e. just adding `,index` to the end of the return command. but this outputs:

```
>>> find_new_similar(tfidf_matrix2, 40, tfidf_matrix)

([(260816, 0.55759049663331683)], 0)
```

but I am actually expecting

```
([(260816, 0.55759049663331683)], 40)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: couldn't you rename `for index in related_docs_indices` to something like `for i in related_docs_indices`, don't reuse the parameter name as a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of index is being replaced in the list comprehension(** in the below code)!

```
return [(index, cosine_similarities[index]) for **index** in related_docs_indices][0:top_n], index
```

Therefore renaming the iteration variable would get the desired result!

```
return [(i, cosine_similarities[i]) for i in related_docs_indices][0:top_n], index
```